# search in string with first occurence and so on

Tags: php

The below code highlights all the word that i searched
,but i want it to search only first occurrence then on button click search other and so on".

```
 function writeMsg(){
 $count = 0;
 $str = "my bird is funny, we fun are funny, they are funny they are fun";
 $keyword = $_GET['search'];
 $copy_date = preg_replace("/$keyword\b/",'<b style=background-             color:yellow;>'.$keyword.'</b>', $str);
 echo $copy_date;
 }


?>
 <html>
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
  Please enter word to search: <input type="text" name="search"><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="NEXT" />
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['search'])){
    writeMsg();
}
?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) you can decide when to replace:

```
$pattern = '/' . preg_quote($keyword, '/') . '\b/';
$index = 0; // only replace first

$copy_date = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($match) use ($index) {
    static $replacements = 0;

    if ($replacements++ == $index) {
        return sprintf('<b style="background-color:yellow;">%s</b>',
            htmlspecialchars($match[0], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
        );
    } else {
        return htmlspecialchars($match[0], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }
}, $str);
```

You can set `$index` to 1, 2, etc. to replace the second match, third match, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Add a

```
<input type="hidden" name="count" value="$count" />
```

marker in your form to know the position after every click.

Combined with @jack s answer that will do.